# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha de un JDatePicker en Net Beans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy usando un `jDatePicker` para que el usuario seleccione la fecha que el indique.

El problema es que no encuentro un método de **retorno de la fecha**.

He buscado mucha información, pero ninguna fue de ayuda.
Espero sus respuestas Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Has probado con `datepicker.getModel().getValue()` ?

Comment: @Diego Alejandro Uribe Blatnik Puedes asignarle una variable `Date()`

Comment: ¿Cuál es la clase `JDatePicker`? Netbeans (hasta donde sé) no tiene un componente llamado `JDatePicker`, supongo que de ser así, entonces estás utilizando una librería externa, o utilizaste el `JXDatePicker`. ¿Podrías aclararnos esto?